# unable to stream to crtmpserver, Error sending data: Broken pipe

Tags: media, gstreamer, rtmp, live-streaming, flv

Using Gstreamer latest version
gst-launch-1.0 version 1.8.1
GStreamer 1.8.1

command :

```
gst-launch-1.0 -m -v --gst-debug-level=2  autovideosrc ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 !  videoconvert ! tcpclientsink host="hidden_ip" port=1935
```

to stream to crtmpserver ( on ubuntu AWS ec2 ) which has following open , publicly accessible and working ports

```
 sudo netstat -putan|grep crtmp
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9999            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7235/crtmpserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1935            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7235/crtmpserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9999            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11734/crtmpserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1935            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11734/crtmpserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9999            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11689/crtmpserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1935            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11689/crtmpserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7235/crtmpserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11734/crtmpserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11689/crtmpserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6665            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7235/crtmpserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6665            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11734/crtmpserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6665            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11689/crtmpserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6666            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7235/crtmpserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6666            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11734/crtmpserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6666            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11689/crtmpserver
```

Error :

ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTCPClientSink:tcpclientsink0: Error while sending data to "hidden_ip:1935".
Additional debug info:
gsttcpclientsink.c(217): gst_tcp_client_sink_render (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTCPClientSink:tcpclientsink0:
Only 236024 of 614400 bytes written: Error sending data: Broken pipe
Execution ended after 0:00:01.308461393

complete error trace
http://pastebin.com/aEFYb5q6

All help much appreciated ,
Thanks in anticipation

---

update :
After some workarounds on iptable and gst plugins 
Im am finally getting seeking query error . Any ideas on how to solve this will be very welcomed

gst script from ubuntu 15.10

```
gst-launch-1.0 -m -v --gst-debug-level=2 v4l2src ! video/x-h264,width=320,height=240,framerate=10/1 ! h264parse ! flvmux ! rtmpsink location ='rtmp://<hidden_ip>/live'
```

traces from gst

```
flvmux gstflvmux.c:1238:gst_flv_mux_write_header:<flvmux0> downstream did not handle seeking query
............
flvmux gstflvmux.c:1246:gst_flv_mux_write_header:<flvmux0> downstream is not seekable, but streamable=false. Will ignore that and create streamable output instead
........
gstbasesrc.c(2948): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 0:00:00.213998674
```

Comment: looks like the tcp server is breaking connection.. possible MTU issue .. why are you streaming raw video - they are big! .. you cannot use h264 encoding? also you need to payload the data .. cannot just go from videoconvert to the tcpsink..

Comment: Hello otopolsky , following your advice i tested form another machine having older gst1.0 , now i am using : gst-launch-1.0 -v -m --gst-debug-level=3 rpicamsrc bitrate=1000000 ! video/x-h264,width=640,height=480,framerate=15/1,profile=high ! h264parse ! flvmux ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://hidden_ip:1935/live'

Comment: now error is rtmp :0:: RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet header

Comment: another error is  "rtmp :0:: RTMP_Connect1, handshake failed."

Comment: arent there any firewall issues? maybe try to sniff the communication with wireshark.. please update(edit) question with what pipe you are using on server and client with that rtmp